# 18.04.6 My USB mouse is no longer detected

Tags: usb

Lubuntu 18.04.6 LTS. My USB mouse is no longer detected. It still works on other computers and used to work on this HP Stream PC13. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: What is the `lsbusb` output? Please, watch syslog while disconnecting and connecting the mouse. [Edit] your question to add this extra information.